# Switch between tabs using a select dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have tabs setup on the desktop view to let the user switch between content. But on mobile I need different behaviour as the tab headings are being hidden and instead I need to use a Select dropdown to switch the content.

The tab inner content is being displayed using a class of `in active` to show the relevant image, and each panel has an id of `tab-pane{{ loop.index }}`.

So I need move the `in active` class each time the select dropdown is changed.

The ID of the Select field is `id="floorplanSelect"`

This is the start of my jquery code which works if there's only two tabs, but not if there's more, so can someone please help, as I'm only a beginner on javascript:

```
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  {% for row in block.floorplans %}
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade{% if loop.first %} in active{% endif %}" id="tab-pane{{ loop.index }}">
    ...tab content...
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
<!-- End tabs -->

<!-- Select dropdown -->
<select id="floorplanSelect" class="form-control" name="floorplan">
  {% set floorplan = craft.request.getParam('floorplan') %}
  {% for rows in block.floorplans %}
  <option value="{{ rows.tabHeading.value }}" name="tab-pane{{ loop.index }}">{{ rows.tabHeading.label }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
<!-- End Select -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#floorplanSelect').change(function(){
  $('.tab-pane').toggleClass( "active in" );
})
</script>
```

Below is a screenshot to help understand what I'm referring to.

[Screenshot of html for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYBT4.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of what you have already tried.

Comment: I need to work out how to target the id of tab-pane{{ loop.index }} twig code via javascript, as currently it's only targeting the tab-pane class.

Comment: dave, you must follow the rules.
a minimal version of your code (even if it does not work), including everything related (e.g HTML markup), must be provided by you.
This is NOT a "Please make this for me" platform.

Comment: apologies. I will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close.
I have removed your code to make it function with pure HTML a JS.
Please note, there are better ways to do this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab-pane1">
    ...tab content1...
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-pane2">
    ...tab content2...
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-pane3">
    ...tab content3...
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End tabs -->

<!-- Select dropdown -->
<select id="floorplanSelect" class="form-control" name="floorplan">
  <option value="tab-pane1">tab1</option>
  <option value="tab-pane2">tab2</option>
  <option value="tab-pane3">tab3</option>
</select>
<!-- End Select -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#floorplanSelect').on('change', function(e) {
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active in')
    $('#' + $(e.currentTarget).val()).addClass("active in");
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Dementic, that's perfect for what i need. Appreciate the help :)